# Starting docker container that is more than 90 days old

Tags: docker, dynamics-business-central

I had created a docker container image for Business Central 2 months ago. Now when I try to start the container it starts with an unhealthy status and Business Central client doesn't work.

`docker start <container-id>`

[image]

I checked the logs that told me that I am trying to run a container which is more than 90 days old.

> Initializing...
>   Restarting Container
>   PublicDnsName unchanged
>   Hostname is MyBCDev
>   PublicDnsName is MyBCDev
>   You are trying to run a container which is more than 90 days old.
>       Microsoft recommends that you always run the latest version of our containers.
>       Set the environment variable ACCEPT_OUTDATED to 'Y' if you want to run this container anyway.
>   at , C:\Run\navstart.ps1: line 54
>   at , C:\Run\start.ps1: line 121
>   at , : line 1

I googled the issue and all I can find is to use the docker run command with accept outdated parameter, but that creates a new container. Whereas I want to start the existing container.

`docker run --env accept_eula=Y --memory 4G microsoft/dynamics-nav`

**How can I start an existing docker container that is more than 90 days old?**

## Update

I did the docker commit using the existing container and repository:tag. But when I ran the container (docker run) using the new image it got stuck somewhere in the middle

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `ACCEPT_OUTDATED=Y` and start the container. If it doesn't worked then try this hack.

Make use of [docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) command.

```
docker commit container-id myimage:v1
```

This will create new docker image out of that stopped container with all the data and config in it.

Run a new docker container out of that image.

This new docker container will be almost same as that of stopped docker container that was 90 days old.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would `docker commit` work without mentioning ACCEPT_OUTDATED parameter?

Comment: Yeah it should. Give it a try.

Comment: I did the docker commit using existing container and repository:image that created the new image. But when I ran the docker based upon the new image it got stuck somewhere in the middle of creating a container process. See the image above in my original post update section.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `ACCEPT_OUTDATED=Y`

```
docker run -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -e ACCEPT_OUTDATED=Y --memory 4G microsoft/dynamics-nav
```

Comment: I have mentioned in my post that `docker run` creates new container. Whereas I want to and I am going to start an existing container.